# Cast Iron orchestration memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory, xsd

I'm having trouble with Cast Iron orchestration that I'm attempting to run in Studio. When I leave the default heap size alone (512MB) the job freezes at around 39K records. When I double the heap to 1024MB (the max) it freezes at 80K records. So it's pretty obvious the job is retaining something every time the loop runs. But what types of looped activities retain data between cycles?

I include an image of my orchestration here to show how simple this job seems to be. Only one javascript function is being used to translate a value (in the Read XML activity). It's a custom function I wrote that uses only local vars (assuming there could be some sort of shared scope between functions - I doubt it.) [Here it is.](https://jsfiddle.net/dcoli/RKe5c/)

The Update activity is also an Insert (this is Cast Iron 6.4).

Is there anything about one of these steps that retains variables from step to step? I'm reusing the same loop variable, which is just a segment ("item") of the translated XML file.

[image: my orchestration]
<sub>(source: [dm2241 at www.columbia.edu](http://www.columbia.edu/~dm2241/membersJob.png))</sub>

Here's the xsd for my membership loop value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2012 (x64) (http://www.altova.com) by Colin MacAllister (Columbia Business School) -->
<!--W3C Schema generated by XMLSpy v2012 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="rss">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="channel" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="title">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="link">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI"/>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="pubDate">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="generator">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI"/>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="language">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="en"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="cgId" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
                    <xs:element name="firstName">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="lastName">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="email">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="accountType">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="member" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
                    <xs:element name="officer" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
                    <xs:element name="officerPosition">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="activeOfficer" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
                    <xs:element name="membershipEndDate" type="xs:string"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="version" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the documented ways to clear up heap memory usage in studio is to 
Ensure the **Show memory usage in status bar** option is selected from the Preference dialog box, a memory bar and trash can icon is displayed at the bottom of studio in the form of a status bar.This memory bar displays how much memory is currently used by Studio,
compared to the total memory that is currently allocated to Studio.

To request that Studio attempt garbage collection, reclaiming any unused memory
inside of Studio, click the trash can icon located to the right of the memory bar.
Clicking the garbage collection trash can icon might reduce the amount of memory
Studio is currently using internally, potentially increasing the performance of
Studio when working with a large project.

Another common reason being , the XML Schema Preferences set , the "Number of child node levels allocated in memory for the schema" on the XML Schema preferences section also determines the number of child node levels allocated in memory, specifying a large number of child node levels can adversely affect the performance of Studio also resulting in OOM errors .
Also check the value set on "Number of recursive node levels", Specifying a large number of
recursive node levels can also adversely affect the performance of Studio.

First suggestion would be to check these preferences and optimize the values used so that you get an optimum performance for your project. However, if these do not help then I would suggest you to contact IBM Support so that they can determine what is causing the bottleneck in your specific case and can help you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a split to break down the Processing. Put the Split Activity after the Execute Query. Name the variable and remap and necessary inputs following the Split.